# arithmetic syntax error in string compare

Tags: shell, shell-script, test

I have written a shell script which takes file name as parameter e.g user/test.txt. I want to make this file parameter optional if user does not wish to provide file name he/she can give as "None"

Inside script I'm just checking if filename parameter contains "None"

```
if [ $filename -eq "NONE" ];then
cmd;
fi
```

When "None" is passed as parameter script works fine but when user/test.txt is passed I get below error message which I don't want to print on console

```
arithmetic syntax error
```

Can somebody help ?

Comment: consider using `bash`'s argument handling. It will help you be more consistent with other programs.

Comment: Not part of *this* problem, but I'd put quotes around that variable (`"$filename"`) in case, e.g., you end up with spaces in there.

Comment: @goldilocks, _spaces_ or any character in`$IFS`, or wildcard characters. Funny how the quotes are put where they're not needed (`"NONE"`) and not where they're needed (typical beginner mistake as that's true that it's counter-intuitive to anyone used to other kinds of languages). Note that `[` itself is a glob character, though because it's not matched in a single word (or as a special case for `zsh`), it doesn't need to be quoted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[ bla bla bla ]` is equivalent to `test bla bla bla`.

From `man test`

```
   STRING1 = STRING2
          the strings are equal

   STRING1 != STRING2
          the strings are not equal

   INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2
```

Therefore you need `=` not `-eq`.

Comment: Ah!! I did silly mistake ..thanks for your answer

Comment: It is traditional to click the tick if the answer works for you, no need to up-vote.

Comment: You upvote if it's a good answer. You accept if it's the best/fittest answer that answers your question. Typically, you'll want  to upvote the answer you accept unless you think it's not a good answer.